# Removing duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am using the following query

```
SELECT SS.sightseeingId AS 'sID'
     , SS.SightseeingName
     , SS.displayPrice AS 'Price'
     , SST.fromDate 
FROM tblSightseeings SS INNER JOIN 
     tblSightseeingTours SST ON SS.sightseeingId =  SST.sightseeingId
WHERE SS.isActive = 1 AND SS.isDisplayOnMainPage = 1
```

and getting result like this

```
sID | SightseeingName                        | Price | fromDate 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | Dinner Cruise Bateaux London (Premier) |    40 | 2009-04-01 00:00:00.000
  2 | Dinner Cruise Bateaux London (Premier) |    40 | 2009-12-29 00:00:00.000
 30 | Jack The Ripper, Ghosts and Sinister   |  35.1 | 2009-04-01 00:00:00.000
 30 | Jack The Ripper, Ghosts and Sinister   |  35.1 | 2009-10-01 00:00:00.000
 40 | Grand Tour of London                   |     0 | 2009-05-01 00:00:00.000
 40 | Grand Tour of London                   |     0 | 2010-05-01 00:00:00.000
 87 | Warwick, Stratford, Oxford and The     |    25 | 2009-04-01 00:00:00.000
 87 | Warwick, Stratford, Oxford and The     |    25 | 2009-11-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want to display the unique records 2 one time 30 one time 40 one time. The duplicate records are due to `SST.fromDate`.

How do I correct my query??

Comment: which date do you want to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try next query:

```
select  SS.sightseeingId, SS.SightseeingName, SS.displayPrice,  MAX(SST.fromDate)
from      tblSightseeings SS inner join 
              tblSightseeingTours SST on SS.sightseeingId =  SST.sightseeingId
where    SS.isActive = 1 and SS.isDisplayOnMainPage = 1
GROUP by SS.sightseeingId, SS.SightseeingName, SS.displayPrice
```

Comment: or you van use MIN (SST.fromDate)... It depends on date you want to see.

Comment: Or you can use the SQL WHATEVER() operator.  Oh wait, that's not in ANSI SQL yet...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the records aren't actually duplicated, because the dates are different.  You could do something like:

```
select  SS.sightseeingId, SS.SightseeingName, SS.displayPrice,  MIN(SST.fromDate) AS FromDate 
from      tblSightseeings SS inner join 
              tblSightseeingTours SST on SS.sightseeingId =  SST.sightseeingId
where    SS.isActive = 1 and SS.isDisplayOnMainPage = 1
GROUP BY ss.sightseeingid, ss.sightseeingname, ss.displayprice
```

Answer (score 1):

try this (example will return the highest date in the group):

```
SELECT   SS.sightseeingId,
         SS.SightseeingName,
         SS.displayPrice,
         MAX(SST.fromDate) 
FROM     tblSightseeings SS
INNER JOIN  tblSightseeingTours SST 
         ON SS.sightseeingId = SST.sightseeingId
WHERE    SS.isActive = 1 and SS.isDisplayOnMainPage = 1
GROUP BY SS.sightseeingId,
         SS.SightseeingName,
         SS.displayPrice
```

Depending on what date you want to show you can select the highest using MAX or the lowest using MIN. If you have other criteria you may need to do a subquery.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it enough to just exclude the

`SST.fromDate`

from the select?

Comment: I have to add this SST.fromDate