# SQL Query to get rid of duplicate records

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Do You Delete Duplicate Records In SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191854/how-do-you-delete-duplicate-records-in-sql)

I have a table with columns:

```
FirstName
LastName
AddressLine1
AddressLine2
City
State
```

For each row, `AddressLine1` is different from `AddressLine2` value. But there are some duplicates rows, in which `AddressLine1` of some records matches with `AddressLine2` of some other record.

I want to get rid of such records mentioned above.

Comment: Have you got any ideas so far? Also, what should happen if the AddressLine1 of one record matches the AddressLine2 of the other record, but FirstName or City or State are different?

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841447/delete-duplicate-sql-records

Comment: is there a primary key?  that will make the statement smaller...

Comment: I love that we expend so much energy correcting and editing and answering such obvious duplicates that have no effort put forth.

Comment: yet another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406854/efficient-query-for-finding-duplicate-records

Comment: yet another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385661/deleting-duplicate-records

Comment: and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716565/how-to-delete-duplicate-entry-by-one-sql

Comment: and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173963/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql

Comment: and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114512/removing-duplicate-rows-using-delete-query

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131085/removing-duplicate-records

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772592/sql-deleting-duplicate-records-in-sql-server

Comment: and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91784/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-rows-in-a-table

Comment: and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173963/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql

Comment: and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162325/sql-duplicate-delete-query-over-millions-of-rows-for-performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get all duplicate records:

```
SELECT P.*
FROM table P INNER JOIN
     table S ON P.FirstName = S.FirstName
            AND P.LastName = S.LastName
WHERE P.AddressLine1 = S.AddressLine2
```

If your table had an ID you could write a delete to remove duplicates like this:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE Id IN (
  SELECT P.Id
  FROM table P INNER JOIN
       table S ON P.FirstName = S.FirstName
              AND P.LastName = S.LastName
  WHERE P.AddressLine1 = S.AddressLine2
)
```

Comment: Having a nearly identical answer, I would point out this is better if the rows are truly duplicates. It fails if for instance family members need their addresses sanitized to the same format.

Comment: I do not have any primary key. I just got all this data in an excel and I copied it to a SQL Server table.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table to itself

```
DELETE a
FROM Table a
JOIN Table b
   ON a.AddressLine1 = b.AddressLine2
```

Comment: Those columns aren't in the table, but the approach is somewhat valid.

Answer (score 0):

Swap out `UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER` with some ID's or names or what have you do easily identify in the future. Then you can hand delete as needed. Or modify what is below into an `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement as needed.

```
SELECT
  t1.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER,
  t2.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER
FROM
  table t1,
  table t2
WHERE
  t1.AddressLine1 = t2.AddressLine2
```